# I can't fill a table from JSON in angular and there is no error

Tags: html, json, angular, ngfor

I am reading through a Query my database,  it executes perfectly the query because i can read through the console the JSON is OK but the table does not fill.

This is my component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-envios',
  templateUrl: './envios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./envios.component.css']
})
export class EnviosComponent {

  constructor(private conexion: ConexionService) {}
  envios: Envio[];
  @Input() idnum: number




  ngOnInit() {
  }

  buscarEnvio()
  {
    const idnum = parseInt((document.getElementById('idenvio')as HTMLInputElement).value);
    console.log(idnum);
    this.conexion.consultarEnvio(idnum);
  }

}
```

And this is my conexion service

```
export class ConexionService {
   envio : Envio[];

  private api = 'http://localhost:8080/ProyectoFinal/webapi';
 consultarEnvio(id: Number)
  {
    const path = `${this.api}/estadoenvio/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Envio[]>(path).subscribe(envio => {
      console.log(envio);
    });;
  }

}
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CC" id="idenvio">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="buscarEnvio()">Buscar</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="col" id="tabla">
    <table class="table table-border">
      <thead>
        <tr class="table-danger">
          <th scope="col">Id del envío</th>
          <th scope="col">Nombre del destinatario</th>
          <th scope="col">Dirreción de envío</th>
          <th scope="col">Código Postal</th>
          <th scope="col">Intentos de entrega</th>
          <th scope="col">Estado del envio</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="table-danger" *ngFor="let envio of envios">

          <td class="table-danger">{{envio.idEnvio}}</td>
          <td class="table-danger">{{envio.nombreDestinatario}}</td>
          <td class="table-danger">{{envio.direccionCompleta}}</td>
          <td class="table-danger">{{envio.codigoPostal}}</td>
          <td class="table-danger">{{envio.numIntentosEntrega}}</td>
          <td class="table-danger">{{envio.idEstadoEnvio}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


  </div>
</div>
```

In case you need it, this is the interface

```
export interface Envio
{
    idEnvio : number;
    nombreDestinatario: string;
    DNINIF: string;
    codigoPostal: string;
    direccionCompleta:string;
    idEstadoEnvio: string;
    numIntentosEntrega: number;

    

}
```

If I debug I can see the Json is correct
[JSON OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgoYF.png)

Comment: Where do you set envios..?

Comment: Hi in my envios component,  envios: Envio[];

Comment: Put the line in the OP where you are setting the variable envios. You need to set it in the method `consultarEnvio`

Comment: I have added envio : Envio[]; at the beginning of the class conexion.service (where consultarEnvio) is, but it still does not work

Comment: That is just typing. You need  return this.http.get<Envio[]>(path).subscribe(envio => {
      console.log(envio);  this.envios = envio;
    });;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning any response to `envio` array. In `subscribe()`, assign the response to `envio`

**Updated Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-envios',
  templateUrl: './envios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./envios.component.css']
})
export class EnviosComponent {

  constructor(private conexion: ConexionService) {}
  envios: Envio[];
  @Input() idnum: number

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  buscarEnvio()
  {
    const idnum = parseInt((document.getElementById('idenvio')as HTMLInputElement).value);
    console.log(idnum);
this.conexion.consultarEnvio(idnum).subscribe(data=>{
    this.envios=data;
   }
  }

}
```

**Updated Service:**

```
export class ConexionService {
  private api = 'http://localhost:8080/ProyectoFinal/webapi';
 consultarEnvio(id: Number)
  {
    const path = `${this.api}/estadoenvio/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Envio[]>(path);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I  litterally copy that from your answer and it still does not work, i have checked the console and JSON is still OK :(

Comment: @NetbeansNoob: See my updated answer. You need to change how you subscribe the to data.

Comment: i tried that but i get this error when it compiles     ERROR in src/app/envios/envios.component.ts(31,54): error TS2551: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?

Comment: No. You have to update the Service as well. See my code

Comment: Pavan you're the best.

Comment: Thank you for everything, you're the real MVP

Comment: @NetbeansNoob: Make sure to mark this as answer, It will help others who are in similar boat

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of improvements:

1. You could use ViewChild to get the element from HTML, maybe just as a learning purpose for you.
2. Make the service method return an observable, do not subscribe in service.
3. Why do you have `idnum` both as input and also as a const? From what I see, you are trying to read the value of an input element, based on which to trigger the reading from the service. Enforce the field to be numeric, and use 2-way binding to set the value of `idnum`.
4. When `(click)="buscarEnvio()"` action is triggered, assign `envios$` variable in EnviosComponent ( `envios$ = this.conexion.consultarEnvio(idnum)` ). `envios$` will be of type `Obervable<Envio[]>`. Afterwards, use `envios$` in html with async pipe --> `*ngFor="let envio of envios$ | async"`.
   Could be more pieces of advice, but I think it's something to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not setting your variable `envios` which is used to display the data (according to your html).

The method `consultarEnvio` returns a promise so you need to set your variable in the callback of your async method.

Your code should look like this:

conexionService:

```
export class ConexionService {
   envio : Envio[];

  private api = 'http://localhost:8080/ProyectoFinal/webapi';
 consultarEnvio(id: Number)
  {
    const path = `${this.api}/estadoenvio/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Envio[]>(path).then(envio => {
      return envio;
    });
  }

}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-envios',
  templateUrl: './envios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./envios.component.css']
})
export class EnviosComponent {

  constructor(private conexion: ConexionService) {}
  envios: Envio[];
  @Input() idnum: number




  ngOnInit() {
  }

  buscarEnvio()
  {
    const idnum = parseInt((document.getElementById('idenvio')as HTMLInputElement).value);
    console.log(idnum);
    this.conexion.consultarEnvio(idnum).then((envioResult) => {
       this.envios = envioResult;
    });
  }

}
 buscarEnvio()
  {
    const idnum = parseInt((document.getElementById('idenvio')as HTMLInputElement).value);
    console.log(idnum);
    this.conexion.consultarEnvio(idnum).then((envioResult) => {
       this.envios = envioResult;
    });
  }
```

Comment: He is actually returning a subscription.. this won’t work I’m afraid..

Comment: @MikeOne you're totally right, it should work if he uses "then" instead of "subscribe" isnt it?

Comment: .. I .. don’t think so? Unless I’m missing something, I don’t see a promise anywhere? Maybe I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: @MikeOne As far as I know, http get returns a promise isn't it? Or maybe we need to call `.toPromise()` after

Comment: By default, httpClient returns an observable. .toPromise would help indeed 